# What is most efficient algo to traverse this sql table tree?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, sorting, tree

So I have the following sql table:

```
CREATE TABLE LINKTABLE (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT,
  quote_id INT,
  article_id INT,
  asset_id INT,
  blog_id INT
);
```

The ids here are references to other tables (`blog`, `article`, etc) with the exception of `parent_id` which references the blog table as well. The idea here is that a `quote` can link an `article` to a `blog` or a `blog` to a parent blog `parent`.

This forms a tree where `articles` are leaves, `blogs` are nodes and `quotes` are branches between nodes and leaves.

Given that I have this table, I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to traverse it. Greedily, I think I can just iterate through all `quotes` and then link nodes together, but that then means that my runtime will be determined by the number of branches I have, which I *think* is factorial time (?).

Does anyone have a better solution?

EDIT: Forgot to add this is in mysql.

EDIT EDIT: One dead end appears to be to include all quotes between any two blogs A and C irrespective of if there is a blog B such that A is a parent of B is a parent of C with the same quote, and *then* removing the A to C connection as being a shorter path. Here ([How to remove cycles in an unweighted directed graph, such that the number of edges is maximised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284469/how-to-remove-cycles-in-an-unweighted-directed-graph-such-that-the-number-of-ed)) seems to imply that that approach is NP-hard.

Comment: The only option you really have is a recursive CTE -- and that only if you are using MySQL 8+.

Comment: @peter, could you focus your question to one problem only? traversing and the "dead end" case are really two different things. Sample data and expected result would also be helpful.